# Converting a PFX for AWS Certificate Manager not working

Tags: ssl-certificate, aws-certificate-manager

I'm having a bit of trouble converting a Trustwave certificate for importing into AWS. I've received a password protected PFX and have run these commands and entered the correct password prompts at every step:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -nocerts -out key.pem
openssl rsa -in key.pem -out server.key
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out cert.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -nodes -nokeys -out chain.pem
```

Once I do that I get four files and plug them into AWS Certificate Manager like so:

```
server.key (Certificate Private Key)
cert.pem (Certificate Body)
chain.pem (Certificate Chain)
key.pem (Not used, but generated by the second command)
```

When I import AWS complains with: `Could not validate the certificate with the certificate chain. Choose Previous button below and fix it.`

So I attempted downloading the Trustwave root cert at https://ssl.trustwave.com/support/support-root-download.php (Domain validation > Download Root Certificate).

I've attempted changing the chain to be a combination of chain.pem as well as stca.crt (the Root Cert supplied). Can't seem to get the right combination and am trying to understand how this works properly.

One thing I noticed is that the chain.pem and cert.pem have this appended at the top of the exported files:

```
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 01 00 00 00 
    friendlyName: ***************
subject=/CN=*************.com/O=*****************/L=Richmond/ST=British Columbia/C=CA
issuer=/C=US/ST=Illinois/L=Chicago/O=Trustwave Holdings, Inc./CN=Trustwave Organization Validation SHA256 CA, Level 1/emailAddress=ca@trustwave.com
```

Do those details matter and if so what do they mean, how do I fix it?

Comment: I have migrated my .pfx certificate from Azure to a .pem file, getting the same error.
Some threads ([link](https://serverfault.com/questions/707139/openssl-on-windows-server-extract-certificate-chain-from-pfx?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)) are talking about a wrong order in the chain by the Openssl pkcs12 command.

Answer (score 0):

```
openssl pkcs12 -in _cert.pfx -nocerts -out certOut.key.pem
openssl rsa -in certOut.key.pem -out certOut.server.key
openssl pkcs12 -in _cert.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out certOut.cert.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in _cert.pfx -nodes -nokeys -out certOut.chain.pem
```

**certificate body**: certOut.cert.pem

**certificate private key**: certOut.server.key

**certificate chain**: certOut.chain.pem

*Copy/paste including the “-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"and “-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----” headers.
Without any top attributes*